# Sub menu in specific location

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with 3 leves (top level > sub level 1 > sub level 2) and I want to display the sub level 1  in the same location independent of the location of the top level menu for that sub menu. Besides that I want the sub level 2 next to the sub level 1 when hovered over the sub level 1 item. Maybe sound a bit confusing so I made a quick **[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi6Gs.png)** and **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qg4p2smo/)**

In the mockup you can see what it should look like if I hovered over Item 3 and Sub Item 3.
I've got it till the point that I have the 2 levels of sub menu besides eachother and the 2nd sub level only appears when hovering the 1st sub level. but I can't get it so that I can go over to the 2nd sub level without it dissapearing and what is the best way to get all the sub menu's in the same spot?

The HTML I currently have:

```
<div class="menu-main-container">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1"> <a href=#>Item1</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2"> <a href=#>Item2</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-5"> <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>

                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-6"> <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>

                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-7"> <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-8"> <a href="#">Sub Sub Item 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-9"> <a href="#">Sub Sub Item 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-10"> <a href="#">Sub Sub Item 3</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-3"> <a href=#>Item3</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-4"> <a href=#>Item4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.menu-main-container > ul {
    text-align : left;
    display : table;
    list-style : none;
    text-transform : capitalize;
    text-decoration : none;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
.menu-main-container ul > li {
    text-align: left;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li {
    display : table-cell;
    position : relative;
    cursor : pointer;
    vertical-align : middle;
    text-align : center;
}
.menu-main-container ul li a {
    text-transform : capitalize;
    text-decoration : none;
    color : #000000;
    font-weight : bold;
    font-size : 16px;
}
/*sub menu level 1*/
 .menu-main-container > ul > li:hover {
    background-color : #003cb3;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li:hover > a {
    color : #fff;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li > ul {
    position : absolute;
    top : 100%;
    width : 615px;
    display : none;
    opacity : 0;
    visibility : hidden;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li > ul > li {
    display : block;
    color : #000000;
    width : 227px;
    padding-right : 0;
    list-style-type : none;
}
.menu-main-container ul li ul li a {
    width : 227px;
}
.menu-main-container ul li ul li:hover a {
    color : #003399;
    /*padding: */
}
.menu-main-container ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
}
.menu-main-container ul li:hover ul {
    display : block;
    opacity : 1;
    visibility : visible;
}
/*sub menu level 2*/
 .menu-main-container ul li:hover ul li ul {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 247px;
    width : 247px;
    display : none;
    opacity : 0;
    visibility : hidden;
}
.menu-main-container > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    list-style-type : none;
}
.menu-main-container ul li:hover ul li ul li {
    border : none;
    width : 227px;
    margin-right : 0;
}
.menu-main-container ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
    display : block;
    opacity : 1;
    visibility : visible;
}
.menu-main-container ul li:hover ul li ul li a {
    color : #000000;
}
.menu-main-container ul li:hover ul li ul li:hover a {
    color : #003399;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to, "...but I can't get it so that I can go over to the 2nd sub level without it dissapearing":-

I assume this means you can't move the mouse cursor over to the second submenu. Actually you can - provided you move the cursor absolutely horizontally so as to stay on the item you were hovering on in the first submenu. But the moment you wander upwards or downwards during the mouse move (as your users would probably do) you are moving off the option you were hovering on so the second submenu disappears! You need to position the menus adjacent to each other with no space in between to prevent this. You could use absolute positioning to do this (ie position:absolute).